# NodeJS: Remove either file/folder based on a path without extension (Design approach)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, fs

I am trying to delete a file or folder based on a path that does not contain an extension.

---

Let us assume I have the following path:

```
/home/tom/windows
```

`windows` can be a folder called windows OR a file called windows.txt

Since the path itself does not contain the extension (.txt), the script needs to guess whether it should delete the folder (if any) or the file (if any).

**Initial approach:**

```
fs.stat(path, (err, stats) ->

/* ---------- RUN IF PATH IS VALID ---------- */

// If we don't have any erros and the path is a directory, 
// simply remove that directory and end here

if (!err && stats.isDirectory())
    fs.rmdir(path, (err) ->
        if (err) then return done(err)

        return done(null, 1)
    )

/* ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -- */


/* ---------- RUN IF PATH IS NOT VALID ---------- */

// If we have an error other than "ENOENT" (non-existend file) 
// then return

if (err.code != 'ENOENT') then return done(err)


// Now we know that the path must be a file, thus verify
// its type and extension then unlink

fs.stat(path + '.txt', (err, stats) ->
    if (err) then return done(err)
    if (!stats.isFile()) then return done(err)

    fs.unlink(path + '.txt', (err) ->
        if (err) then return done(err)

        done(null, 1)
    )

)
```

---

**Explanation:**

Test if path exists via fs.stat then check if it is a directory.
If it is a directory, simply remove it and end the execution.

Continue if the conditions in the previous step do not match.
Inspect as to why the conditions did not match (err.code).
If the error is not for a non-existend file, end the execution.

[ELSE]

Continue since we know that the path must be file, since we previously checked whether it is a directory.
Append the extension (.txt) and make sure the file really exist.
If it does, simply unlink the file.

---

**Another approach:**

I could append the extension directly to the path and use fs.unklink() and test for an error code called EISDIR. If false, path must be a valid file therefore remove it. If true, delete dir

```
fs.unlink(path + '.txt', (err) ->
    //Path is a valid file, thus remove
    if (!err) then return done(null, 1)

    //Path is not valid file, thus check if directory
    if (err.code != 'ENOENT' && err.code != 'EISDIR')
      return done(err)

    //Path is directory so remove it
    fs.rmdir(path, (err) ->
        if (err) then return done(err)

        done(null, 1)
    )
)
```

---

**Conclusion?**

Are there any improvements, solutions or desgin concepts?

Comment: You sure you're not over-thinking this?

Comment: I know it is quite complicated but in the end I want to use such approach on other FS methods too.  For instance ```rename()```. The problem is that the path does not contain the extension beforehand.

Comment: It's not complicated at all, that's why I wondered why you're so concerned about it.

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton I was quite concered because my initial approach is quite heavy.  I think the second approach is the way to go. I don't know if this could be improved further though,

Comment: Personally I'd prefer the first approach. There's nothing heavy at all, it's a dozen lines of code...

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the first approach is that it is calling ```fs.stat``` twice. That's something I want to avoid though, Then again, the second approach calls rmdir whenever the path is not a valid file, causing it to not return EOENT for that missing file.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I solved this problem by writing a nodeJS module.

The engine captures a folder and/or file based on a path, using a promised asynchronous control-flow. So exactly what I needed.

It does not matter whether a folder and file share the same name, or if the extension is not known. 
The engine tries to capture either one, based on provided options.

The module is open-source and available via NPM and Github:

https://github.com/Burnett01/fs-capture

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-capture